# Global variables with internal linkage in inline functions

Tags: c++, global-variables, inline-functions

I have a `val.h` source code file with the global variable with internal linkage and inline function that returns its address:

```
// val.h
#pragma once
static int val;
inline int* get_val()
{
  return &val;
}
```

Then this header is included in two different translation units. If I call `&val` in both of these units, I get two different addresses, and it's ok since `val` has an internal linkage and each translation unit has its own `val`. But if I call `get_val()` in both of these units, I get two equal addresses.

Is such behavior guaranteed by the standard, would we always obtain the same value returned by `get_val()` call from any translation unit?

And what if compiler decides to make true inlining, i.e. just to replace `get_val()` call by `&val` statement in each translation unit. Would we get different addresses for each translation unit in such case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function violates the [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) since the expression `val` refers to different entities in different translation units.

Its behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Do you mean the following statement: _There can be more than one definition... as long as all of the following is true: ... name lookup from within each definition finds the same entities_?

Answer (score 1):

As you have it you will get undefined behaviour when you include this header file in two different translation units. This is because expression `return &val` will refer to two different objects; Thereby, the body of `getVal` is different in both translation units, but `getVal` has external linkage. So you violate the one definition rule.

To overcome this, you'd have to define internal linkage for `getVal`, too, i.e. write `static int* get_val() { ...`. Keyword `inline` alone will not define external or internal linkage.